# Magento double tax calculation

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, tax

i set up my own magento store and configured the tax fpr germany 19% Mwst.
The calculation in the cart is wrong it take 2.19% of the product prices.

i am using magento 1.9.2 and here is my tax configuration:

[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSdZn.png) 
 [picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfbgN.png) 
 [Picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhDec.png) 
 [Picture 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etlZv.png)

> E.G. If a Product = 50 € and tax = 19% shipping = no tax 20 €
>
> It should look like: 50€ + 9,5 € +20 € = 79,5 € 
>        but it looks like this: 50 € + 9,5 € + 20 € = 89 € (2x 9,5 € calculation)

Hope u can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by checking the tax calculation step by step. The problem was the extension Paypal payment Free. After uninstalling this the calculation worked fine.